# How to solve java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException in a maven spring project?

Tags: java, maven, reflection, java-17, java-platform-module-system

I wanted to update a spring application built with maven from java 8 to java 17 but because of the Java Platform Module System, I got the following exception:
`Unable to make field private byte[] javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec.key accessible: module java.base does not "opens javax.crypto.spec" to unnamed module @234523ab`.

As I read in previous posts, I tried to open the package `javax.crypto.spec` to all unnamed modules by adding the following plugin to my `pom.xml` file:

```
<plugin> 
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <argLine>@{argLine}
      --add-opens java.base/javax.crypto.spec=ALL-UNNAMED
    </argLine>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

However, I still get the same exception. Does anyone know how to fix this problem within a maven spring application?
Also, I read that `--add-opens` should only be used as a work-around, so does anyone knows a better solution?

Comment: When does the exception happen? When you compile the project, or when you run it? (This makes a big difference.) Also, can you try to get the stack trace?

Answer (score -2):

Although it is generally not recommended, it is possible to make a field accessible by changing memory directly using unsafe reflection.

```
public static void forceAccessible(AccessibleObject ao) {
    try {
        Field unsafeField = Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
        unsafeField.setAccessible(true);
        ((Unsafe) unsafeField.get(null)).putBoolean(ao, 12, true);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException|NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This code uses unsafe reflection to change the value of field "override" directly in memory. This field determines whether or not the field is accessible.